# Polymer grunt: Fatal error: spawn dev_appserver.py ENOENT

Tags: gruntjs, polymer, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to run the [Polymer Docs](https://github.com/polymer/docs) locally, but I get an error when trying to serve the app with grunt:

```
Running "appengine:run:frontend" (appengine) task
executing: dev_appserver.py --port=3000 --host=0.0.0.0 .
Fatal error: spawn dev_appserver.py ENOENT
```

[(Full output)](http://pastebin.com/T3ZFAiQw)

The only relevant info I could find was [this on the polymer-dev forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/LYdNEtqC3fU/2vpW7_XnVUsJ), but in that case the issue was using the incorrect Google App Engine SDK. I am using the Python SDK and I'm running Python 2.7.9.

**EDIT:** If you're finding this now, it's much easier to avoid this issue and use Gulp instead, basing it off of the [Polymer Starter Kit gulpfile](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same troubles on Ubuntu 14.04. The solution for me was to add the **absolute path** to the Google App Engine Python SDK directory to my `$PATH` environment variable.

1. Edit shell startup script (I'm assuming you're using bash):

   `vim ~/.bashrc`
2. Add the absolute path to Google App Engine directory:

   `PATH="$PATH:/absolute/path/to/google_app_engine"`
3. Save and close file.
4. Remember that the changes won't take effect until the next time your shell starts up, so close and re-open your terminal now.

If that doesn't help, keep in mind that the `ENOENT` error generally means that a script is trying to access a file or directory that doesn't exist. So, for some reason, the path that Grunt is using to access the Google App Engine is incorrect.

Comment: That fixed that problem. Now it seems to be getting stuck later on in the process, but at least I'm further along!